# Binding a CollectionViewSource to a ListBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

For some reason I cannot get my `ListBox` to display data from my `CollectionViewSource`. Here is the code...

```
public class AppTest
{
    public int Priority { get; set; }
    public string TestName { get; set; }
}

public class AppTestProvider
{
    public List<AppTest> GetAppTests()
    {
        return new List<AppTest>()
        {
            new AppTest() { Priority=1, TestName = "Application Setup" },
            new AppTest() { Priority=2, TestName = "File System Permissions" }
        };
    }
}
```

... and now the Xaml...

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="AppTests" ObjectType="{x:Type Application:AppTestProvider}" MethodName="GetAppTests" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" Source="{Binding AppTests}">
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Priority" Direction="Ascending" />
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="TestList" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TestName}" />                    
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

If I change the `ItemsSource` of the `ListBox` to look like this (getting data from the `ObjectDataSource` and *not* the CVS) it displays the data albeit not sorted...

```
<ListBox x:Name="TestList" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource AppTests}}">
```

I'm sure this must be something pretty simple. I just cannot seem to get it to work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace this `<CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" Source="{Binding AppTests}">`

with `<CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" Source="{StaticResource AppTests}">`.

You are `referring to resource` defined in XAML so you need to use `StaticResource` instead of `Binding` to refer to `ObjectDataProvider` just like you are doing in later approach to set ItemsSource of your listBox.